# creating a table in oracle takes extra time

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using below code to crate table, which should have to take max 30 min. But some time it takes more than 90 minutes. please help me to modify it

```
    create table age_temp
    as
    SELECT co.circle, co.canumber, sum(age1) age1, sum(age2) age2, sum(age3) age3,         sum(age4) age4,
            sum(age5) age5, sum(age6) age6, sum(age7) age7, sum(age8) age8
    FROM
    (SELECT cta.szpartitionfield circle, cta.ifield1 CANUMBER,
            CASE WHEN ohstatus IN ('CO','CM') THEN
                    ohopnamt_doc
                 ELSE CASE  WHEN ohstatus IN ('IN','FC') THEN
                                    CASE WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,ohrefdate) < 1  THEN
                                            ohopnamt_doc
                                    ELSE 0
                                    END
                            ELSE 0
                            END
                 END age1,
            CASE WHEN ohstatus IN ('IN','FC') THEN
                      CASE WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,ohrefdate) >= 1  AND
                                MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,ohrefdate) < 2  THEN
                                    ohopnamt_doc
                           ELSE 0
                           END
                 END age2,
            CASE WHEN ohstatus IN ('IN','FC') THEN
                      CASE WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,ohrefdate) >= 2  AND
                                MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,ohrefdate) < 3  THEN
                                    ohopnamt_doc
                           ELSE 0
                           END
                 END age3,
            CASE WHEN ohstatus IN ('IN','FC') THEN
                      CASE WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,ohrefdate) >= 3  AND
                                MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,ohrefdate) < 4  THEN
                                    ohopnamt_doc
                           ELSE 0
                           END
             END age4,
        CASE WHEN ohstatus IN ('IN','FC') THEN
                  CASE WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,ohrefdate) >= 4  AND
                            MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,ohrefdate) < 5  THEN
                                ohopnamt_doc
                       ELSE 0
                       END
             END age5,
        CASE WHEN ohstatus IN ('IN','FC') THEN
                  CASE WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,ohrefdate) >= 5  AND
                            MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,ohrefdate) < 6  THEN
                                ohopnamt_doc
                       ELSE 0
                       END
             END age6,
        CASE WHEN ohstatus IN ('IN','FC') THEN
                  CASE WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,ohrefdate) >= 6  AND
                            MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,ohrefdate) < 7  THEN
                                ohopnamt_doc
                       ELSE 0
                       END
             END age7,
        CASE WHEN ohstatus IN ('IN','FC') THEN
                  CASE WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,ohrefdate) >= 7  THEN
                                ohopnamt_doc
                       ELSE 0
                       END
                  ELSE 0
                  END age8 
     FROM 
         CDCDATA.ORDERHDR_ALL ORD, cash_temp ct, CDCDATA.customer_all cu, CMS_CDC.COL_TRN_AGREEMENT cta where ct.customer_id = ORD.customer_id 
     and ord.customer_id = cu.customer_id
     and cu.custnum = cta.szlegacyagreementno ) co 
     GROUP BY  co.circle, co.canumber;
```

Comment: Obviously the time taken depends on `SELECT` performance. To get help you have to post execution plan of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting details of actual data and table structures of base tables (or other tables) used in this query - it is difficult to modify the query. But below might be helpful:

1. Check if any other process is running at the same time of creation of this table when it is taking more than expected time. May be some  other process is blocking one if these tables or taking all resources.
2. Check parallelism - use no parallel and see how long it takes and play with that parameter. Need to consider parallel level of base tables.
3. Split this query into multiple queries - You are currently processing data by case , group by, etc. Split each operation into separate query.

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this with a pivot (below may not exactly work since I don't have sample data, but should put you on the right track):

```
WITH prep AS (
  SELECT
      cta.szpartitionfield circle
    , cta.ifield1 canumber
    , CASE
        WHEN ohstatus IN('CO', 'CM') THEN 1
        ELSE MAX(MIN(CEIL(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, ohrefdate)),8),1)
      END piv_col
      -- Round the 'months_between' up and cap it at 8
      -- Then force CO and CM stats to be 1 since we want them added in there
      -- Make sure no negatives or 0s get in... probably not needed
    , CASE WHEN ohstatus IN('IN', 'FC') THEN ohopnamt_doc ELSE 0 END ohstat
      -- Will only be non-zero for IN or FC status
    FROM cdcdata.orderhdr_all ord
      INNER JOIN cash_temp ct
        ON ord.customer_id = ct.customer_id
      INNER JOIN cdcdata.customer_all cu
        ON ord.customer_id = cu.customer_id
      INNER JOIN cms_cdc.col_trn_agreement cta
        ON cu.custnum = cta.szlegacyagreementno
)
SELECT *
  FROM prep PIVOT(
    SUM(ohstat) -- Sum, split by values 1-8
    FOR (piv_col) IN (
      1 AS age1, 2 AS age2, 3 AS age3, 4 AS age4
    , 5 AS age5, 6 AS age6, 7 AS age7, 8 AS age8
    )
  )
;
```

That should produce a result set that looks like this:

```
CIRCLE   CANUMBER  AGE1  AGE2  AGE3  AGE4  AGE5  AGE6  AGE7  AGE8
------- --------- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
a               1     5     1     5    12     1     0    12    16
b               2     2     5    12     7     4     2     3     3
c               3     0     3     2     1     0    21     5     3
d               4     1     2     1     1     7     5     3    11
```

Hopefully that helps!

If it doesn't, please post `DESCRIBE` output for each table and some sample data (5ish rows) from each table that relate to each other.

Also, you aliased your tables, but columns `ohstatus` `ohrefdate` `ohopnamt_doc` aren't aliased, so I had to do the prep work on the whole join rather than the specific table (I kinda assume they come from `cdcdata.orderhdr_all`), which might save some processing time.

Comment: Yes, you are right. ohstatus, ohrefdate and ohopnamt are from orderhdr_all i.e ord. the tables orderhdr_all, customer all and col_trn_agreement has more than 300 coloumns and 1000000+ records. And i don't have rights for indexing.

Comment: did you try to do the pivot to see if that query performed faster (thus speeding up table creation)?